# Animation & Complexity of Graph Editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor

[image]

This is an example. The character's arm is passing through space using all X, Y, and Z axes.

[image]

I tried to get the least key, but many keys were created to represent the curve.

I don't have the knowledge to edit 3D animations, so I am not confident to adjust the timing in this situation to create a nice tension sense.

[image]

Imagine a moving character with various poses. Rigify will create more channels.

From my point of view, the graph editor is too complex to represent good timing and smooth arcs.

But I think there will be channel management methods and graph editing methods that I don't know.

Please let me know the keywords of the techniques needed to solve my problem and I will study hard.

Thank you.

---

**Additional questions:**

I want to be checked by you to see if what I have realized is correct.

3D character animation seems to be better suited to frame-by-frame work, such as drawing animation or stop-motion animation.

Only a few in-betweens are automatic. It is a little convenient point of 3D animation.

Graph editing appears to be effective for camera or simple object motion.

Did I realized exactly?

and what is the best interpolation for in-between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For timing adjust use the dopesheet instead: if you select some keyframes, you can grab them and scale them (time cursor is the pivot point).

Put the timeline in a point: if you right click an the left you will select all keyframes before the timeline, if you right click on the right you will select all keyframes after.

Try also select a group of keyframes and press Shift T and move the mouse, for easing in and out.

Another great way to control the timing is to use the breakdowner in the T panel, pose tools tab (but you have to start with less keyframes).

[image]

Comment: Thank you.

I didn't know the In-Between feature.

Let me try it.

The Shift T function is also very useful.



I've had additional questions and fixed the posting. Please check.

Comment: We are entering the field of opinions, every animator will find his best workflow. I generally work in a pose-to-pose way, then add inbetweens, using Bezier interpolations (generally, not always). I use the graph editor to edit "single movements", i.e. the height of a hip bone or the rotation of a mechanic arm. Graph is useful also to "read" the flow of movements, that can be smoothed and tweaked quite easily. The more inbetweens you set, the more the animation is "yours" and not standard. Some animators suggest to key every frame, for study purposes, without any automatic computer influence!

Comment: I learned a lot. Thank you for sharing your time.